# Please help me Calculate convergence in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

## setup

r.v. $X \sim Bin(n, p)$.

Let $a, b$ be constant.

## Question

We want to show that
$$
\sqrt n \left[ -\frac{a+b}{a+b+n}\cdot \frac{X}{n} + \frac{a}{a+b+n} \right] \overset{P}{\to} 0 \mathrm{\ \ \ as\ } n \to \infty.
$$

## What I know

**Theorem**
$$
\mathbb E[(Y_n - c)^2] \to 0 \Longrightarrow Y_n \overset{P}{\to}c
$$

I tried to use this theorem, but it diverges to infinity with $n$ remaining in the molecule.
Please give me an idea to show this.

Comment: I think you must have $p=\frac{a}{a+b}$? Then, if it is the case, you just wan to compute the variance of your quantity which is given by $\frac{a+b}{n(a+b+n)}^{2}n(p)(1-p)=\frac{(a+b)p(1-p)}{n(a+b+n)^{2}}$. Then check that the quantity multiplied by $n$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Maybe almost sure convergence could help since implies convergence in probability.

Comment: Did you try computing the expectation (or the second moment)?